# Function to set attributes to elements

Tags: javascript, html

new to JS and trying to figure out how to set attributes to elements using a loop. I tried the code below for kicks, and it didn't seem to work:

```
  attArr.forEach((item) => {
    element.setAttribute(item, attArr[item]);
  });
```

However, the below works. What gives?

```
  for (const item in attArr) {
    element.setAttribute(item, attArr[item]);
  }
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `x in y` You are iterating using keys. And when you do forEach you are calling a function for each item in array `y`. What you want to do is probably more like this

```
 Object.keys(attArr).forEach( key => {
    element.setAttribute(key,attArr[key]);
  });
```

Comment: Beat you to it :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful to see the rest of your code.

The `for...in` is iterating over object entries

Here is the same using forEach

```
Object.entries(attArr).forEach(([key,val]) => element.setAttribute(key, val));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the first example is that `attArr[item]` causes an `undefined`.

if you want reply the behaviour of the second example using a foreach, you have to do the following:

```
attArr.forEach((item, index) => {
  element.setAttribute(index, attArr[item]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer it in a simple way, `forEach` will iterate over the items, `for...in` will iterate over the keys.

```
const arr = ['Meat', 'Cheese']

arr.forEach(item => {
   console.log(item)
})

# Output 'Meat' 'Cheese'

for(const item in arr){
  console.log(item);
}

# Output '0' '1'
```